# How to define a method from a gem to use within a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to build a gem and I want to define a method `my_method` inside the gem and use it inside a model.

Example:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    my_method
end
```

My gem:

```
#lib/my_gem.rb
require "my_gem/model_inclusions"
module MyGem

end

#lib/my_gem/model_inclusions.rb
module MyGem
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def my_method

    end

  end
end
```

When I try the example it gives me `undefined method 'my_method' for <Class:0x00000045434> (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module NumberInternationalizer
 def my_method
  ...
 end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :extend, NumberInternationalizer
```