# Move model method from Rails app to a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a gem on Rails 5.

Let's say I have `SomeModel` with a `hello` method, which I use within `myengine`:

```rb
# app/models/myengine/someModel.rb
module Myengine
  class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
    def self.hello
      puts 'hello world'
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to **remove `hello` method from default application and store it into a gem** so I can plug it in only if I need to.

I don't know neither **what to write** to extend the model nor **where to place** that file.

I tried to fo through the [Rails guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes), but they are way too complicated! I got lost after several tries.
I don't need Single Table Inheritance, I need to extend that specific model.

Tried already [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209935/extend-a-rails-model-in-a-gem) which seems not quite right, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052427/how-to-define-a-method-from-a-gem-to-use-within-a-model) which doesn't unfortunately say much.

Any idea?

Comment: maybe you should just write module with `hello` method and extend model within application not gem itself?

Comment: what do you mean by "write module with `hello`" and by "extend model within application not gem itself"? I need a gem as this is part of a wider thing I'm doing which has to be replicated easily on several Rails applications.

Comment: Hey @Aleksey, I think I nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after digging the web and crashing my head against the wall I've finally come to a conclusion.

Suppose you want to extend the features of `SomeModel` in your default application engine `myengine`:

```rb
# app/models/myengine/some_model.rb
module Myengine
  class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
    # some code
  end
end
```

You can either do it in your `config/intializers` folder or in the `lib/myplugin` folder. I show both, the first on the **concern way**, the second using the **self way**.

---

#### The Concern way

In your gem you can extend `SomeModel` adding the `hello` method using *Concern*:

```rb
# myplugin/config/initializers/some_model_extension.rb
module Myplugin::SomeModelExtension

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def hello
        return "Hello world!"
    end
  end

end

class Myengine::SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Myplugin::SomeModelExtension
end
```

You can update `ClassMethods`, but the same goes for `InstanceMethods` (if you don't know the difference between instance methods and class methods you should [read this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/)).

If you want to add associations like `has_many` or `belongs_to` you can use `included do` as [this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858075/1498118).

---

#### The *self* way

This works as well

```rb
# myplugin/lib/myplugin/some_model_extension.rb
module SomeModelExtension

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def hello
      return 'Hello world'
    end
  end

end

class Myengine::SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SomeModelExtension
end
```

```rb
# myplugin/lib/myplugin.rb
require 'myplugin/some_model_extension'
```

---

If you want to read more, check [Rails Guidelines](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Also it's worth checking this [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858075/1498118).

---

Comment: Seems like you did a great job! But why you don't use `ActiveSupport::Concern`?

Comment: Yep, I've gone that way as well. I'm still improving the answer as it's not quite right yet. But almost there. I have problems with association... that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, the concern way it's fine. The second way is ok, but couldn't understand how to make associations work. It doesn't really matter as far as I can use *concern* ;-)

Comment: you should use it! =)